# Infragistics ultragrid with datatable binding

Tags: multithreading, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have a ultragrid which is bound to a datatable, i update datatable in a thread (not a gui thread). My question is that while updating datatable do I need to delegate it on gui thread (so that update on grid happens in gui thread) or I can simply update datatable in any thread and infragistics grid takes care of updating itself in correct thread?

I couldn't find answer to simple question in infragistics online help or docs.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the data source on the UI thread.  There are some similar discussions on the Infragistics forums, for example: [one](http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/p/15711/57341.aspx#57371), [two](http://community.infragistics.com/forums/p/15832/57635.aspx), [three](http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/p/43259/237710.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

best way i found to do this was to use a synchronizationContext object to post the .add call to the GUI thread.

in my situation i have classes with a property of type synchronizationContext that i set to SynchronizationContext.Current when the class is initialized. then i can call something like:

SyncContext.Post(Sub()
                   _displaySource.Rows.Add(r)
                   End Sub, Nothing)

when the class is running on a different thread and it works fine. without this you will get the annoying red X occasionally